# Network MP3 player recomendations

Tags: mp3, home-networking, lan

I'm looking for a device with the following capabilities

- WiFi a/b/g/n any will do, WPA support
- Connect to my Windows machine and play non DRMd mp3s from it, Zune device or software integration would be a bonus
- ~$200 or less
- music controlled/selected from the device rather than a seperate PC, a remote would be great
- Multi-zone support would be cool but not essential
- Easy to use by non-techies

I've looked at a number of products

- Chumby - mp3 support seems poor
- Roku Soundbrige - very mixed reviews, seems fairly orphaned but pretty cheap
- Logitech Squeezebox - Kinda pricey but looks good
- Sonos - woah! Expensive

Does anybody here have any experience with these or other products they could share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a squeezebox (from before they were bought by Logitech), and am very happy with it.  It can be controlled either by the included remote (or your universal remote) or via the embedded webserver.  I have it playing off of a server running on my NAS, so I don't need to have a computer on all the time.  That may be one drawback if your computer isn't on 24/7.  One oddity is that it won't even display the time if not connected to a server.

Comment: I went with a squeezebox and so far, so good! Really neat litlle machine!

Answer (score 1):

have a look at **[Terratec's NOXON](http://www.terratec.net/en/products/noxon.html)** products (prices range from €169 to €249):

Tens of thousands of Internet radio stations and podcasts from all over the world, as well as full integration of music portals - all over the Internet and without a computer. **In addition, hear music from your hard drive, all over the house**!

**NOXON iRadio**

[image]

**NOXON iRadio Cube**

[image]

**NOXON iRadio for iPod**

[image]

File Formats

```
* Internet radio (streaming MP3, MMS)
* MP3 (up to 320 kBit/s, CBR/VBR)
* WMA-9 (up to 320 kBit/s) unprotected and Windows Media DRM10 protected
* ID3 V1.0 / V2.0
* AAC+
* M3U
* PLS
* WAV
```

Network Security

```
* WEP encryption (64/128 bit key support)
* WPA / WPA2 encryption
```

Datarates

```
* 54 Mbit/s (WLAN)
* 10/100 Mbit/s (Ethernet)
```